# Tabbing through a form in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a tab indexing problem in IE7, my form is centered, and when focus hits a select box the whole form moves to the left and the select box is aligned to the left margin.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
var iTabIndex = 0;
$(document).bind('keydown', 'tab', function() { $('input, select').eq(++iTabIndex).focus();});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any css that is changing the browser default styling of the select element, like padding or margins? If so you might find that adding the same selector with the :focus pseudo class for that line of css will fix the issue.

If not, then please post a jsfiddle example and I will take a proper look.

Also, can I ask why you are changing the tab index? It is generally best avoided if possible (mainly for accessibility reasons I believe).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the first paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Sorry, the editor didn't like the angled brackets that I used to specific 'select' with. Edited so that it should read properly now.